# How to add dynamic meta tags to website with no middleware or SSR

Tags: create-react-app, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have a relatively large app where there are a lot of user profile pages. I want to make it so that if you share one of the user's profile page it will preview their name and picture on social medias like FB and Twitter (think sharing a Twitch streamer's page on Twitter). I used create-react-app to start the project so I don't have server side rendering or any middleware for pre-rendering tools. Is there another way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There two ways you can get this to work

1. Is the server your files via express server and check for who has the made the request by checking user-agent header from request and if its a bot instead of sending them the usual response you can fetch the required user profile data and use that data to populate the open-graph metatags and return them the HTML with those metatags.
2. Second way would be to use a network interceptor from the CDN you're using to identify the who is requesting the page (either bot or a person) if its a bot, make a request to your backend to fetch related data and send them the HTML with populated metatags.

Explained approach

Every time a request comes into our server, it comes with a header value `user-agent` which tells the server who is requesting the resources (human or a bot from Facebook trying to do link preview). Just by comparing a list of known user-agent (so it won't work on all but will work all know platforms and 90% of others.)

Let's say we have something.com where we want the link preview and let's say a request comes for something.com/john. What we will do is check for request that is coming to the server and will check for `user-agent` property, if its a human it will be redirected to our normal site but if its a bot (so it just wants an HTML for link preview) what we are going to do is since it's our server we can grab the data of akkshay and set the proper metatags inside our HTML and send it back as a response.

So what happens here is whenever a human tries to go for something.com/john he will be redirected to our landing page as he is more concerned about what he sees on his browse but when a bot comes in we will send it HTML response with proper metatags as its the link previews which is the concern for the bot.

This thing can be done on our express server with something like [this](https://github.com/justswim/cra-metatag-demo/blob/master/server.js). But this can also be done infrastructure level.